# Form doesn't submit form data populated via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm having the following problem with my code below: when 'productSearchResult' is populated via AJAX, the contents are not included when the form is submitted using the 'Add' button.

**UPDATE 1:**
Strangely it is working, but only the first time productSearchQuery is populated. Any subsequent populations of productSearchQuery run into the problem above.

**HTML:**

```
<form name="productSearch">
    <input name="productSearchQuery" type="textbox">
</form>
<form name="productAdd">
  <div id="productSearchResult"></div>
</form>
<a>Add</a>
<div id="addResult"></div>
```

**HTML loaded via AJAX into productSearchResult:**

```
    <input type="radio" name="productId" value="3944">
    <input type="radio" name="productId" value="3946">
    <input type="radio" name="productId" value="3999">
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function postData(type, url, data, targetDiv) {
    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            $(targetDiv).html(response);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error! Plese try again.');
        }
    });
    return false;
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[name=productSearchQuery]').keyup(function() {
        // submit the form
        postData('POST', 'search.php', $('form[name=productSearch]').serialize(), '#productSearchResult');
    });

    $('a').click(function() {
        postData('POST', 'add.php', $('form[name=productAdd]').serialize(), '#addResult');
    });

});

</script>
```

**UPDATE 2:**
OK, first off I want to apologise for not including this code in my original post, I honestly didn't suspect it could be the cause. I've fixed my code after rolling back the JS which is returned with the radio buttons. I can't understand why the new JS causes the problem above, whereas the old JS does not.

**Here's the old JS that works fine:**

```
$('tr.product input[type=radio]').hide();

$('tr.product').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('blueHover');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('blueHover');
});

$('tr.product').click(function(event) {
    $('tr.product').removeClass('blueChecked');
    $(this).closest('tr').addClass('blueChecked');

    if (event.target.type !== 'radio') {
        $(':radio', this).attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

**Here's the new JS that causes the problems above:**

```
$('tr.product input[type=radio]').hide();

$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('td', $(this).parent()).addClass('blueHover');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('td', $(this).parent()).removeClass('blueHover');
    },
    click: function (event) {
        $('tr.product').removeClass('blueChecked');
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('blueChecked');

        if (event.target.type !== 'radio') {
            $(':radio', $(this).parent().parent()).attr('checked', false);
            $(':radio', $(this).parent()).attr('checked', true);
        }
    }
}, 'tr.product td');
```

Comment: Are you selecting any radio button before click Add button?

Comment: Yes I am, and the radio button is 'checked' in the HTML.

Comment: Are the radio buttons included in the form. if not then how will they get post

Comment: The radio buttons are loaded into the 'productSearchResult' DIV, which is inside the form.

Comment: Can you yourself open the Dev tool `F12` in the browser and check what is happening through the console and track your ajax request

Comment: I've updated my post with the latest findings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function postData(type, url, data, targetDiv) {
    $.ajax({
        type: type,
        url: url,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: data,
        success: function(response) {
            $(targetDiv).html(response);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('Error! Plese try again.');
        }
    });
    return false;
};

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[name=productSearchQuery]').keyup(function() {
        // submit the form
        postData('POST', 'search.php', $('form[name=productSearch]').serialize(),     '#productSearchResult');
    });

    $('a').click(function() {
        postData('POST', 'add.php', $('form[name=productAdd]').serialize(), '#addResult');
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Can you also explain the issue in the original code!

Comment: This just caused no response to be received after posting the forms.

Comment: Hi, apologies, I found the problem in some JS which I didn't think to include in my original post. I still don't understand exactly what is wrong with the code that has caused the problem, so I've updated my post with the good and bad code in the hope that someone can tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [jQuery on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function() {
     postData('POST', 'add.php', $('form[name=productAdd]').serialize(), '#addResult');
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still only works the first time with this solution.

Comment: Hi, apologies, I found the problem in some JS which I didn't think to include in my original post. I still don't understand exactly what is wrong with the code that has caused the problem, so I've updated my post with the good and bad code in the hope that someone can tell me.